# How should I understand this phrase?

Tags: meaning

> His eyes were sharp and piercing, save during those intervals of torpor to which I have alluded.

What is the meaning of the second part of the sentence?

Comment: Have you looked up "save", "interval", "torpor", and "allude"? Please include the definitions of the words you're struggling with. (Also, make sure you don't have any typos; I see at least five.)

Answer (score 1):

"Save for" typically means "except".

So in this case, his eyes were sharp and piercing, but not (*except*) when he was in periods of torpor.

"To which I have alluded" means that the speaker has already mentioned or made reference to the periods of torpor.

Comment: Correct answer: links to the definitions would make the answer complete.